# Create loop for uploaded document in PHP

Tags: php, loops, file-upload

I am looking to create a loop for uploading several documents (49 to be exact).  I am completely new to loops.  Here is my current code:

```
$folder="uploads/";

    if(isset($_FILES["t1url"])) {
        $t1urlextension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["t1url"]["name"]));
        $t1urlname = "M1s1t1url";
        $t1urldoc_loc = $_FILES['t1url']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($t1urldoc_loc,$folder.$t1urlname.".".$t1urlextension);
    }

    if(isset($_FILES["t2url"])) {
        $t2urlextension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["t2url"]["name"]));
        $t2urlname = "M1s1t2url";
        $t2urldoc_loc = $_FILES['t2url']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($t2urldoc_loc,$folder.$t2urlname.".".$t2urlextension);
    }
```

I have this working for these 2 but the thought of changing this over and over again 49 times seems brutal.

Essentially there are 10 locations that would need to increase by one

```
if(isset($_FILES["t1url"])) {
```

"t1url" to "t2url" to "t3url" etc.

```
$t1urlextension =
```

"$t1urlextension" to "$t2urlextension" to "$t3urlextension" to etc.

```
end(explode(".", $_FILES["t1url"]["name"]));
```

"t1url" to "t2url" to "t3url" to etc.

```
$t1urlname
```

"$t1urlname" to "$t2urlname" to "$t3urlname" to etc.

```
"M1s1t1url"
```

"M1s1t1url" to "M1s1t2url" to "M1s1t3url" to etc.

```
$t1urldoc_loc
```

"$t1urldoc_loc" to "$t2urldoc_loc" to "$t3urldoc_loc" to etc.

```
$_FILES['t1url']['tmp_name'];
```

"t1url" to "t2url" to "t3url" to etc.

```
move_uploaded_file($t1urldoc_loc,$folder.$t1urlname.".".$t1urlextension);
```

"$t1urldoc_loc" to "$t2urldoc_loc" to "$t3urldoc_loc" to etc.

"$t1urlname" to "$t2urlname" to "$t3urlname" to etc.

"$t1urlextension" to "$t2urlextension" to "$t3urlextension" to etc.

### Update

Here is the solution I was able to come up with based on JTC's answer:

```
    $url = array("t1url","t2url");
    $extension = array("t1ext","t2ext");
    // $name = array("t1name","t2name");
    $tab = array("M1s1t1url","M1s1t2url");
    $loc = array("t1loc","t2loc");
    $folder="Uploads/";
    $arrlength = count($url);

    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        if(isset($_FILES[$url[$x]])) {
            $extension[$x] = end(explode(".", $_FILES[$url[$x]]["name"]));
            // $name[$x] = $tab[$x];
            $loc[$x] = $_FILES[$url[$x]]['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($loc[$x],$folder.$tab[$x].".".$extension[$x]);
        }
    }
```

Works perfectly!

### Update

I spoke to soon!  I can get this to work for 4 but anything over 4 will not work.  Here is the code that works:

```
    $url = array(
        "t1url",
        "t2url",
        "t3url",
        "t4url");
    $extension = array(
        "t1ext",
        "t2ext",
        "t3ext",
        "t4ext");
    $tab = array(
        "M1s1t1url",
        "M1s1t2url",
        "M1s1t3url",
        "M1s1t4url");
    $loc = array(
        "t1loc",
        "t2loc",
        "t3loc",
        "t4loc");
    $folder="Uploads/";
    $arrlength = count($url);

    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        if(isset($_FILES[$url[$x]])) {
            $extension[$x] = end(explode(".", $_FILES[$url[$x]]["name"]));
            $loc[$x] = $_FILES[$url[$x]]['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($loc[$x],$folder.$tab[$x].".".$extension[$x]);
        }
    }
```

This for some reason does not work:

```
    $url = array(
        "t1url",
        "t2url",
        "t3url",
        "t4url",
        "t5url");
    $extension = array(
        "t1ext",
        "t2ext",
        "t3ext",
        "t4ext",
        "t5ext");
    $tab = array(
        "M1s1t1url",
        "M1s1t2url",
        "M1s1t3url",
        "M1s1t4url",
        "M1s1t5url");
    $loc = array(
        "t1loc",
        "t2loc",
        "t3loc",
        "t4loc",
        "t5loc");
    $folder="Uploads/";
    $arrlength = count($url);

    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
        if(isset($_FILES[$url[$x]])) {
            $extension[$x] = end(explode(".", $_FILES[$url[$x]]["name"]));
            $loc[$x] = $_FILES[$url[$x]]['tmp_name'];
            move_uploaded_file($loc[$x],$folder.$tab[$x].".".$extension[$x]);
        }
    }
```

Here is the error message I am receiving in the code that does not work:

I get this 5 times:

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
> C:\wamp2\www\phpKiosk\mc1.php on line 535

Here is line 535:

> $extension[$x] = end(explode(".", $_FILES[$url[$x]]["name"]));

I get this error once:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at C:\wamp2\www\phpKiosk\mc1.php:535) in
> C:\wamp2\www\phpKiosk\mc1.php on line 773

Here is line 773:

> header("location: http://localhost/phpkiosk/mc1.php");

Comment: Loops are a commonly discussed topic in basic programming. You would benefit from reading a book or conducting more self-research, and asking the community *specific* questions about the challenges you're facing. Most of us aren't here to write programs for you.

Comment: @Litty my apologies.  I did not mean to offend.  I am really new to programming.  I am not looking for a hand out.  Would you recommend any books?  I am always looking to learn more.

Comment: We're simply strict about Q&A content, no need to worry! Resources are difficult to find if you're not sure what you're looking for. The PHP manual might be your best choice right now, particularly the control structure pages: http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: @CraigHowell I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and the loop over it.

```
$array = array("file1,file2,file3,file4");

foreach($array as $item){
 // your upload code
}
```

But more elegant way to upload your files would be using [glob](http://php.net/glob) like this.

```
$files = glob('upload/*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    // your upload script
}
```

Update:
Based on your problem I would try to use this:

```
$path = $_FILES[$url[$x]]["name"];
$extension[$x] = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Instead of this:

```
$extension[$x] = end(explode(".", $_FILES[$url[$x]]["name"]));
```

Comment: thanks!  I will definitely look into these two options and review the links you sent.

Comment: I may have spoke too soon. I assumed that if 2 would work in the loop that 49 should be no problem. For some reason with the code I have in my update showing the solution it will not go past 5. I have checked the syntax and there are no issues there. I have even skipped a a few after the 5th to see if there was an issue with the 6th or 7th and that didn't fix it. Do you have any ideas as to why this would happen?  I can post the full code if that is necessary.

Comment: Yes post it, but first you do not use foreach but for, are you sure your $arrlength is too 49, so it loop over every item in array?

Comment: The $arrlength is a count of the $url array so it should always be the correct number for the loop.  I even replaced it with just the number 5 and it would not work.